# How to create a new array from an simple array combining all the parameters using PHP

Tags: php

I have an array in Php.

```
 $my_array = ["student_id_1", "student_id_2", "student_id_3", "student_id_4", "student_id_5", "student_id_6"];
```

I want to use the array above ro create a new array with elements in the following order:

```
 $newArray = [ ["student_id_1","student_id_2"],
               ["student_id_1","student_id_3"],
               ["student_id_1","student_id_4"],
               ["student_id_1","student_id_5"],
               ["student_id_1","student_id_6"],
               ["student_id_2","student_id_1"],
               ["student_id_2","student_id_3"],
               ["student_id_2","student_id_4"],
               ["student_id_2","student_id_5"],
               ["student_id_2","student_id_6"],
               ["student_id_3","student_id_1"],
               ["student_id_3","student_id_2"],
               ["student_id_3","student_id_4"],
               ["student_id_3","student_id_5"],
               ["student_id_3","student_id_6"],
          ...
          and the code continues 
        ];
```

The array will multiple by itself, I think to use a nested for loop to do that, but in the new array the same element must not be in the same row.

How can I generate an array like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer to my question.

```
$elements = ["student_id_1", "student_id_2", "student_id_3", "student_id_4", "student_id_5", "student_id_6"];

foreach ($elements as $element1) {
 foreach ($elements as $element2) {
     if ($element1 != $element2)
        echo $element1. " - ".$element2."\n";
 }
```

}